# How to close ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

bootstrap in my angular 2 project. I have two buttons in my modal as well. Each button have a callback function as well. How can I implement modal `close` or call modal `close` from the button? Went through the document but, felt quiet hard to understand.

The following is my button config:

```
private _modalConfig: any = {
        title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Lesson?',
        button: [{
            text: 'Delete',
            class: 'btn-delete',
            callback: ()=>{
                            console.log(event);
                            alert('this is Delete');
                          } 
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            class: 'btn-cancel',
            callback: ()=>{  
                            event.preventDefault(); 
                            alert('this is Cancel');
                          } 
        }]
    }
```

Comment: *Hi am using ng-bootstrap. for some reason cant edit my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ModalDirective, of ng2-bootstrap, then the proper method is

`.hide()`, which allows to manually close the modal.

Answer (score -1):

If you are included the bootstrapjs into your site.

It should be like this:

```
angular.element('#modal').modal('hide');
```

This is the very basic way to close bootstrap modal.